# Orgmode + Mac (el capitan): can't find latex

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

I'm running Orgmode 8.2.10 on a Mac (El Capitan) and I'm trying to use `C-c C-x C-l` to preview some latex formulas. However, using the mentioned shortcut produces the error:

`Can't find "latex" (needed to convert LaTeX fragments to images)`

I have the following on my `.emacs`:

`(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin/gs:/Library/TeX/texbin/"))`

and I even tried adding `:/Library/TeX/texbin/latex`, which is where my "latex" is.

Comment: It may be a symbolic link that is broken due to an upgrade or something.  Try locating the actual location and use that instead.  For example, mine is at: `...texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Comment: If you've installed LaTex via Macports recently, then latex is probably located at `/opt/local/libexec/texlive/texbin/latex`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem with you on my Mac(El Capitan), and the colon ":" maybe affects.
After I delete the colon ":", the preview works in my Emacs.
Here is my code on my `.emacs`:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (append '("/Library/TeX/texbin") exec-path))
```